# ¿Por qué me muestra los nombre de las columnas de la base de datos y no los nombre de variables de mi clase?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Les comento:
Estoy intentando aprender `Angular` y tengo un **DataTable** con la data directa desde `SQL`, pero necesito trabajar la data en la **clase "Paises"** y no consigo hacerlo (ya que al obtener la data me mantiene los nombre de columnas de la base de datos y no la estructura que tiene mi clase y constructor)... lo siguiente es mi código:

```
// Fetch all articles
  obtenerPaises(): Observable<Paises[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiPais + '/obtener-pais')
              .map(this.extractData)
         .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Correspondiente a **paises.service.ts** para obtener la data desde `SQL`.

```
paises: Paises[];
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.obtenerPaises();
    this.paises = await this.obtenerPaises();
    this.fn_cargarTablaPaises(this.paises);
  }

  obtenerPaises(): Promise<any> {
    return this.paisesService.obtenerPaises().toPromise();
  }
```

Correspondiente a **paises.component.ts** para obtener la data e ingresarla en un **datatable**

```
export class Paises {
public vliPaisId: number;
public vlsPaisNombre: string;
public vlsAcciones: string;

constructor(piPaisId: number, psPaisNombre: string) {
    this.vliPaisId = piPaisId;
    this.vlsPaisNombre = psPaisNombre;
}

fnGenerarAcciones() {
    return('hola');
}
```

Correspondiente a **paises.ts** que contiene la **clase Paises** (el tipo ocupado en la variable para almacenar la respuesta de la data).

Resulta que cada vez que intento acceder a **vliPaisId** o realizar un `console.log` no me muestra la estructura de la clase, sino el nombre de las columnas de la **BD**.

Ejemplo:

```
console.log(this.paises);

0: {pais_id: 1, pais_nombre: "CHILE"}
1: {pais_id: 2, pais_nombre: "PERU"}
2: {pais_id: 3, pais_nombre: "ARGENTINA"}
3: {pais_id: 4, pais_nombre: "BRASIL"}
4: {pais_id: 5, pais_nombre: "PARAGUAY"}
5: {pais_id: 6, pais_nombre: "ALEMANIA"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Aplicado en el **component** obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?
¿Cómo podría hacer para que respete la estructura de mi **clase** y así poder realizar métodos dentro de aquello?

La idea es que quiero que en el **DataTable** puede haber otra columna en la cual puede trabajar la información, colocar botonería, etc.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Déjame ver si entiendo bien. Quieres ser capaz de manipular el objeto que recibes con el listado de paises compuesto por {id, nombre} ¿Cierto? y quieres ser capaz de poder añadir mas cosas al objeto... ¿Podrías por favor colocar esto en tu código y mostarme el console.log?

// En el servicio:
obtenerPaises() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiPais + '/obtener-pais').
  }

// En el componente donde vas a usar el listado de paises:
constructor(private: paisesService: PaisesService) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.paisesService.obtenerPaises().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}

Comment: Exactamente, mi objeto de la **clase Paises** tiene id, nombre y acciones (este último es el que quiero manipular, pero ni siquiera aparece en el _console.log_), pero al hacer el **console.log** ni siquiera me mantiene los nombres de variables correspondientes al **objeto**

Agregaré el **console.log**

Comment: `Response {_body: "[{"pais_id":1,"pais_nombre":"CHILE"},{"pais_id":2,…ARAGUAY"},{"pais_id":6,"pais_nombre":"ALEMANIA"}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(2), _normalizedNames: Map(2)}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:3000/pais/obtener-pais"
_body: "[{"pais_id":1,"pais_nombre":"CHILE"},{"pais_id":2,"pais_nombre":"PERU"},{"pais_id":3,"pais_nombre":"ARGENTINA"},{"pais_id":4,"pais_nombre":"BRASIL"},{"pais_id":5,"pais_nombre":"PARAGUAY"},{"pais_id":6,"pais_nombre":"ALEMANIA"}]"
__proto__: Body`

Comment: Veo que en _body: es donde vienen los datos por lo menos mas organizados ¿Porque no almacenas eso en una variable dentro del componente donde vas a hacer uso de la tabla? ya estando dentro de una variable podrías empezar a manipular los datos.
this.paisesService.obtenerPaises().subscribe((data: any) => {
this.paises = Array.from(data._body);
}); }

Answer (score 1):

Typescript no tiene tipado fuerte, es decir, que aunque puedes definir unos tipos de datos mientras programas, luego en tiempo de ejecución sigue siendo javascript y el tipo de los datos no se checkea.

En el código

```js
        obtenerPaises(): Observable<Paises[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiPais + '/obtener-pais')
                  .map(this.extractData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
       }
```

Le dices al compilador que lo que tu api devuelve es un observable de Paises, pero no es cierto, porque tu api devuelve objetos de otro tipo.

Y luego cuando haces esto

```js
    this.paises = await this.obtenerPaises();
```

estás asignando un array de objetos del tipo incorrecto a una variable que debería contener solo objetos del tipo País, pero nuevamente como esta comprobación la haces en tiempo de ejecución, no te da errores.

Mi recomendación primeramente sería cambiar la llamada a la API y tipearla de manera correcta

```js
    {pais_id: number, pais_nombre: string}
```

de esta manera ya tendrías una visualización más clara de lo que debes corregir.

El segundo paso, lo que yo haría, es aprovechar la implementación que tienes del operador rxjs map acá
`.map(this.extractData)`
En la función **extractData** deberías iterar sobre la respuesta que recibes y mapear los datos de la api a los datos de tu clase País. Ya que tienes Pais definido como clase, lo mejor es usar el constructor y para cada elemento llamar a `new Pais(id, nombre)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré.